# Why is this code causing a SegFault at result.create?

Tags: delphi, segmentation-fault, freepascal, lazarus

I've got a list of about 10K names & addresses that needs cleaning, I've managed to get the addresses cleaned and am now extending the program to cater for the other fields, my code compiles without any issues, however when I try to run the program highlighting the following

```
000000010000DD9E 743d                     je     0x10000dddd 
<SYSTEM$_$TOBJECT_$__$$_CREATE$$TOBJECT+125>
```

The only create command in the code relates to a stringlist that I'm using to store splitted info before casting it to a variable, before sending it to a seperate SdfDataSet, my code worked perfectly when I was just dealing with the addresses so why is it now failing? I thought it might be because seperate stringLists were required but creating anymore than one list causes the same problem.

Forgive the fairly large chunk of code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  title, str1, str2, str3, str4, address : String;
  result : TStringList;

begin
  // Add field to address data set
  AddressData.FieldDefs.Add('Title', ftString); // 0
  AddressData.Schema.Add('Title');
  AddressData.FieldDefs.Add('Fore', ftString); // 1
  AddressData.Schema.Add('Fore');
  AddressData.FieldDefs.Add('Sur', ftString); // 2
  AddressData.Schema.Add('Sur');
  AddressData.FieldDefs.Add('Address', ftString); // 3
  AddressData.Schema.Add('Address');
  AddressData.Active := True;
  AddressData.Edit;

  result.Create;  // This seems to be the problem

  // Begin export
  with Initial_Data do begin
  for i := 1 to RecordCount do
   begin
    RecNo := i;
    title := Fields[13].AsString;
    str1 := Fields[8].AsString;
    str2 := Fields[9].AsString;
    str3 := Fields[10].AsString;
    str4 := Fields[11].AsString;

    // Clean Titles
    // Split at first space or period
    if title <> '' then
      begin
        ExtractStrings([' ', '.'], [' '], PChar(title), result);
        title := result[0];
      end
    else title := null;


    // Concentate Addresses
    // Check markup of string 1
    if (AnsiEndsStr(',', str1) = False) then
      str1 := str1 + ', '
    else
      if (AnsiEndsStr(',', str1) = True) then
        str1 := str1 + ' ';

    // Check markup of string 2
    if (AnsiEndsStr(',', str2) = False) then
      if str3 = '' then
        str2 := str2
      else
        str2 := str2 + ', '
    else
      if (AnsiEndsStr(',', str2) = True) then
        if str3 <> '' then
          str2 := str2 + ' ';

    // Markup for string 3
    if (AnsiEndsStr(',', str3) = False) then
      if str4 = '' then
        str3 := str3
      else
        str3 := str3 + ', '
    else
    if (AnsiEndsStr(',', str3) = True) then
      if str4 <> '' then
        str3 := str3 + ' ';

    // Cleanup final string
    if (AnsiEndsStr('.', str4) = True) then
      begin
        ExtractStrings(['.'], [' '], PChar(str4), result);
        str4 := result[0];
      end
    else
      if (AnsiEndsStr(',', str4) = True) then
      begin
        ExtractStrings([','], [' '], PChar(str4), result);
        str4 := result[0];
      end;

    // Compile address
    address := str1 + str2 + str3 + str4;

    // Add records to address
    with AddressData do
      begin
        RecNo := i;
        Insert;
        Fields[0].AsString := title;
        Fields[3].AsString := address;
        Post;
      end;

    if result[0] <> '' then
    result.Free;

  end; // Close of for loop
end;

  AddressData.Refresh;
end;
```

Comment: `result := TStringList.Create;`

Comment: Doh! That seems to have done the trick, it's now throwing an exception about converting a null variant into a string which I can deal with. Thanks for the assist :)