# SIGSEV error on pascal class use

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Uing the following class code in Lazarus I get the following error on the  writeln(woman.name, 'has been born'); line: "Project My Application raised exception class 'External SIGSEV'.  Other pascal code seems to work ok

```
program project1;
uses wincrt;

type human = class
   private
      health : integer;
   public
      name : string;
      constructor born(n: string);
end;

constructor human.born(n: string);
begin
  name := n;
  health := 100;
end;

var
  woman : human;

begin
  woman.born('Tracy');
  writeln(woman.name, 'has been born');
end.
```

Comment: [Why is this code causing a SegFault at result.create?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286349/why-is-this-code-causing-a-segfault-at-result-create#comment39405941_25286349)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate object this way:

```
woman := human.born('Tracy');
```